# WiX VS Project, after switching to NuGet package Heat is not running

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, wix, nuget

I am  using VS2017, there is installed WiX Toolset 3.11.1. I have add HarvestDirectory Item to the project file.

**wixproj file:**

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <HarvestDirectory Include="SourceDir\$(Configuration)">
      <PreprocessorVariable>var.HarvestPath</PreprocessorVariable>
      <DirectoryRefId>INSTALLFOLDER</DirectoryRefId>
      <ComponentGroupName>HeatGenerated</ComponentGroupName>
      <SuppressRootDirectory>true</SuppressRootDirectory>
      <SuppressCom>true</SuppressCom>
      <SuppressRegistry>true</SuppressRegistry>
    </HarvestDirectory>
  </ItemGroup>
```

We decided to include WiX toolset via NuGet package. After installing the NuGet package the project fails to build and the current reason is that Harvest is not running  anymore.

We are using following nuget package.

```
Install-Package WiX -Version 3.11.1
```

to reproduce the error run command above on any 3.11.1 WiX projects and try to build it after.

*The error was complaining about missing definition of some attribute. do not have access to dev box at the moment will update later.*

What else we need to to to make VS build the project the same way as with intalled WiX Toolset?

Comment: `We decided to include WiX toolset via NuGet package. After installing the NuGet package the project fails to build`- Do you mean you add the package WiX toolset to the project via NuGet? If yes, which nuget package are you using and what is the build error?

Comment: If possible, could you please share a sample to reproduce this issue? I do not think everyone is familiar with HarvestDirectory.

Comment: Some info about `HarvesDirectory` can be found [here](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/reference/heat/)